# How can I access a rails view variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am a rails newbie and I just want to extract a rails object and attribute (@tracks.audio) using javascript. I want to apply audio files dynamically from the db instead of using the hard coded version seen on commented lines 1,2,3

Here is the tracks.js.erb

```
    // Event listener for DOM
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", theDOMHasLoaded, false);

// array of audio files (stored in a folder called music)
var files = ["<% @tracks.audio %>" , // this code doesn't work!
      "chooseyourweapon.mp3", // 1
      "interlude.mp3", // 2
      "scriptures.mp3" // 3
      ];

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Find and store audio info
///////////////////////////////////////////////

// array for AudioObjects
var audioList = [];
// components and the index for their AudioObject
var componentDict = {};
// store AudioObject that is currently playing
var playingAudio = null;
// store playhead id if one is being dragged
var onplayhead = null;

/* AudioObject Constructor */
function AudioObject(audio, duration) {
  this.audio = audio;
  this.id = audio.id;
  this.duration = duration;
}
/* bindAudioPlayer
 * Store audioplayer components in correct AudioObject
 * num identifes correct audioplayer
 */
AudioObject.prototype.bindAudioPlayer = function (num) {
  this.audioplayer = document.getElementById("audioplayer-" + num);
  this.playbutton = document.getElementById("playbutton-" + num);
  this.timeline = document.getElementById("timeline-" + num);
  this.playhead = document.getElementById("playhead-" + num);
  this.timelineWidth = this.timeline.offsetWidth - this.playhead.offsetWidth
}

/* addEventListeners() */
AudioObject.prototype.addEventListeners = function () {
  this.audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate, false);
  this.audio.addEventListener("durationchange", AudioObject.prototype.durationChange, false);
  this.timeline.addEventListener("click", AudioObject.prototype.timelineClick, false);
  this.playbutton.addEventListener("click", AudioObject.prototype.pressPlay, false);
  // Makes playhead draggable 
  this.playhead.addEventListener('mousedown', AudioObject.prototype.mouseDown, false);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}

/* populateAudioList */
function populateAudioList() {
  var audioElements = document.getElementsByClassName("audio");
  for (i = 0; i < audioElements.length; i++) {
    audioList.push(
      new AudioObject(audioElements[i], 0)
    );
    audioList[i].bindAudioPlayer(i);
    audioList[i].addEventListeners();
  }
}

/* populateComponentDictionary() 
 * {key=element id : value=index of audioList} */
function populateComponentDictionary() {
  for (i = 0; i < audioList.length; i++) {
    componentDict[audioList[i].audio.id] = i;
    componentDict[audioList[i].playbutton.id] = i;
    componentDict[audioList[i].timeline.id] = i;
    componentDict[audioList[i].playhead.id] = i;
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Update Audio Player
///////////////////////////////////////////////

/* durationChange
 * set duration for AudioObject */
AudioObject.prototype.durationChange = function () {
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  ao.duration = this.duration;
}

/* pressPlay() 
 * call play() for correct AudioObject
 */
AudioObject.prototype.pressPlay = function () {
  var index = getAudioListIndex(this.id);
  audioList[index].play();
}

/* play() 
 * play or pause selected audio, if there is a song playing pause it
 */
AudioObject.prototype.play = function () {
  if (this == playingAudio) {
    playingAudio = null;
    this.audio.pause();
    changeClass(this.playbutton, "playbutton play");
  }
  // else check if playing audio exists and pause it, then start this
  else {
    if (playingAudio != null) {
      playingAudio.audio.pause();
      changeClass(playingAudio.playbutton, "playbutton play");
    }
    this.audio.play();
    playingAudio = this;
    changeClass(this.playbutton, "playbutton pause");
  }
}

/* timelineClick()
 * get timeline's AudioObject
 */
AudioObject.prototype.timelineClick = function (event) {
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  ao.audio.currentTime = ao.audio.duration * clickPercent(event, ao.timeline, ao.timelineWidth);
}

/* mouseDown */
AudioObject.prototype.mouseDown = function (event) {
  onplayhead = this.id;
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', AudioObject.prototype.moveplayhead, true);
  ao.audio.removeEventListener('timeupdate', AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate, false);
}

/* mouseUp EventListener
 * getting input from all mouse clicks */
function mouseUp(e) {
  if (onplayhead != null) {
    var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(onplayhead)];
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', AudioObject.prototype.moveplayhead, true);
    // change current time
    ao.audio.currentTime = ao.audio.duration * clickPercent(e, ao.timeline, ao.timelineWidth);
    ao.audio.addEventListener('timeupdate', AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate, false);
  }
  onplayhead = null;
}

/* mousemove EventListener
 * Moves playhead as user drags */
AudioObject.prototype.moveplayhead = function (e) {
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(onplayhead)];
  var newMargLeft = e.pageX - ao.timeline.offsetLeft;
  if (newMargLeft >= 0 && newMargLeft <= ao.timelineWidth) {
    document.getElementById(onplayhead).style.marginLeft = newMargLeft + "px";
  }
  if (newMargLeft < 0) {
    playhead.style.marginLeft = "0px";
  }
  if (newMargLeft > ao.timelineWidth) {
    playhead.style.marginLeft = ao.timelineWidth + "px";
  }
}

/* timeUpdate 
 * Synchronizes playhead position with current point in audio 
 * this is the html audio element
 */
AudioObject.prototype.timeUpdate = function () {
  // audio element's AudioObject
  var ao = audioList[getAudioListIndex(this.id)];
  var playPercent = ao.timelineWidth * (ao.audio.currentTime / ao.duration);
  ao.playhead.style.marginLeft = playPercent + "px";
  // If song is over
  if (ao.audio.currentTime == ao.duration) {
    changeClass(ao.playbutton, "playbutton play");
    ao.audio.currentTime = 0;
    ao.audio.pause();
    playingAudio = null;
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// Utility Methods
///////////////////////////////////////////////

/* changeClass 
 * overwrites element's class names */
function changeClass(element, newClasses) {
  element.className = newClasses;
}

/* getAudioListIndex
 * Given an element's id, find the index in audioList for the correct AudioObject */
function getAudioListIndex(id) {
  return componentDict[id];
}

/* clickPercent()
 * returns click as decimal (.77) of the total timelineWidth */
function clickPercent(e, timeline, timelineWidth) {
  return (e.pageX - timeline.offsetLeft) / timelineWidth;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////
// GENERATE HTML FOR AUDIO ELEMENTS AND PLAYERS
///////////////////////////////////////////////

/* createAudioElements
 * create audio elements for each file in files */
function createAudioElements() {
  for (f in files) {
    var audioString = "<audio id=\"audio-" + f + "\" class=\"audio\" preload=\"true\"><source src=\"http://www.alexkatz.me/codepen/music/" + files[f] + "\"></audio>";
    $("#audio-players").append(audioString);
  }
}

/* createAudioPlayers
 * create audio players for each file in files */
function createAudioPlayers() {
  for (f in files) {
    var playerString = "<div id=\"audioplayer-" + f + "\" class=\"audioplayer\"><button id=\"playbutton-" + f + "\" class=\"play playbutton\"></button><div id=\"timeline-" + f + "\" class=\"timeline\"><div id=\"playhead-" + f + "\" class=\"playhead\"></div></div></div>";
    $("#audio-players").append(playerString);
  }
}

/* theDOMHasLoaded()
 * Execute when DOM is loaded */
function theDOMHasLoaded(e) {
  // Generate HTML for audio elements and audio players
  createAudioElements();
  createAudioPlayers();

  // Populate Audio List
  populateAudioList();
  populateComponentDictionary();
}
```

Comment: Well, normally you would just use a controller which sends the file? Or use it as an asset? I'm not entirely sure what your problem or source of confusion is? I don't know what you expect `<% @tracks.audio %>` to do? Show a file URL?

Comment: the javascript code above creates an audio player. I do not believe <% @tracks.audio %> does anything actually because I don't expect javascript to interpret ruby, but i know there must be a way for javascript to get what i have stored in the db and display it on the index page like so,( example link  http://codepen.io/katzkode/pen/ZbxYYG ) , i just don't know how to do that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use the 'gon' gem. Found here: https://github.com/gazay/gon. With this you are able to pass your rails variables to your JS.

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'gon'
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<head>    
  <%= include gon %>
</head>
```

**your_controller.rb**

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Define your variable and now you can pass it in JS
    @variable = YourModel.all
    gon.new_variable = @variable
  end
end
```

Now 'gon.new_variable' is available in your JS file.

Comment: Thanks, going to try it asap!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this:

- Setting window variables
- Passing data attributes to an object
- The Gon gem (mentioned in another answer)
- Making a JSON endpoint and calling it from Javascript (basically an API).

Some of the solutions I mentioned are explained in this video:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Watch it and choose the option that suits your needs, keep in mind there are also other ways to do this that I didn't mention.

Comment: Thanks, I watched the video and decided to go with the gon implementation. So far so good.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Usually we use:

```
var variable_a = '<%= my_fav_variable %>'
```

or

```
var variable_b = '<%= raw %>'
```